# Executing angularjs function within jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Any ideas how when the user selects the jquery select function, the code can execute the selectResults() (angular function) and pass in the user selected value?

```
minLength: 2,
delay: 500,
select: function (event, ui) {
    $('#fwSearch').val(ui.item.selectedValue);

    debugger;
    //navigate to the FirewallDetail page.
    selectResults($('#selectedUnit').val(ui.item.selectedValue));
}
```

Comment: I think your approach is wrong, angular does not expose any scope's methods to global, never. The thing you want to use is `directives`, yet I suggest you to follow the tutorial before everything http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it by using directive.
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZFj4rz

In this example, it uses `source` and `onselect` attributes for
handling autocomplete source and select event.

```
app.directive('autocomplete', function() {
  return { 
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      source: '=',
      onselect: '='
    },
    link: function( scope, elem, attrs ) {
      $(elem).autocomplete({
        source: scope.source,
        delay: 500,
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          scope.onselect( ui.item.value );
        }
      });
     }
  };
});
```